# Queuing commands in Korn shell

Tags: shell, ksh

I am using AIX Korn shell to execute a Perl script that accepts a numeric argument from 1 to 50 and runs them in the background simultaneously. Is there a way to limit the background process like 5 for example? If one finishes, execute the next one. My current code just executes all of them in the background.

```
i=1; while [[ $i -le 50 ]]; do perl some_script.pl $i &; ((i+=1)); done;
```

For example, if 2 finishes, execute the next one which is 6 and so on.

Comment: BTW, do you know *which version* of ksh your AIX release bundles? This would be helpful not only for people adding answers, but also for folks who want to know to which other operating systems an answer applies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy .Sorry. I had no Idea that there were various versions of ksh for AIX. I'm on AIX 7.2.0.0 and I googled how to get the Korn shell version. I pressed CTRL+ALT+V and got Version M-11/16/88f. Would this be it? Thanks

Comment: If you run the default shell, you have ksh88. What is the shebang of your script, and if you do not run it in a script, what is the output of `$SHELL --version`

Comment: --version does not appear to be a flag on the current ksh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various versions of KSH around. The original Korn Shell, `ksh88` is the default shell in IBM AIX since version 4 (`/usr/bin/ksh`). But they also support the Enhanced Korn Shell, `ksh93` (`/usr/bin/ksh93`), which has more bells and whistles. It are those bells and whistles which make life easy in this case:

**KSH93:** In KSH93, you have a shell variable `JOBMAX` which does this for you:

> **`JOBMAX`:** This variable defines the maximum number of running background jobs that can run at a time.  When this limit is reached, the shell will wait for a job to complete before starting a new job.

```
JOBMAX=5
i=1; while [[ $i -le 50 ]]; do perl some_script.pl $i &; ((i+=1)); done;
```

Btw. you might be interested in using a for-loop instead.

```
JOBMAX=5
for i in $(seq 1 50); do perl some_script.pl "$i" &; done
```

**KSH:** If you cannot use KSH93 and have to stick to the POSIX 2 compliant KSH, you might consider using `xarg`, but only if it allows the `--max-procs` flag.

```
seq 1 50 | xargs -I{} --max-procs=5 perl some_script.pl {}
```

Sadly, [AIX does not support the `--max-procs` flag](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds6/xargs.htm).

So, you have to build something yourself:

```
procmax=5
for i in $(seq 1 50); do
   perl some_script.pl "$i" &;
   (( i%procmax == 0 )) && wait
done
```

Unfortunately, this is not really a true parallel version as it will wait until the first 5 processes finished before it starts the next batch of 5.

So, you could have a look at `jobs` and do something with that:

```
procmax=5
checkinterval=1
for i in $(seq 1 50); do
  perl some_script.pl "$i" &;
  while [[ $(jobs -l | wc -l) -ge "$procmax" ]]; do
    sleep "$checkinterval";
  done
done
```

This is still not perfectly parallel, due to the `sleep`, but it will have to do.

Comment: I tried JOBMAX but didn't seem to work. All processes ran in the background simultaneously. I modified the code to JOBMAX=3
i=1; while [[ $i -le 6 ]]; do perl some_script.pl $i &; ((i+=1)); done;. Does this have to do with the ksh version that was previously asked? Also the for-loop didn't work as it could not find seq.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, can you check if it runs with ksh93? I'm looking into it, but from the manual of IBM, it seems your `ksh` does not support this? Neither your `xarg` which would allow parallelization. Do you have GNU toolkit installed? (check for `gxarg` and `gawk`)

Comment: @criz I am reffering to this : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_varsused.htm

Comment: Funny I was actually working on the same thing but sleeping for 2 seconds before proceeding to the next one. But sadly I still can't use seq though. Also I used the condition `ps -fu $USER | grep some_script.pl | wc -l ` -ge $JOBMAX inside the while loop instead.

Comment: Sorry I don't think gxarg and gawk are available.

Comment: Thanks @kvantour this helped me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. One comment though, don't use `ps` as this gives all some_scipt.pl and not the ones in the loop you want to parallelize. Furthermore, if you want to use `ps`, you might want to do `s -fu $USER | grep [s]ome_script.pl | wc -l` to exclude the `grep` from the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177180/discussion-between-criz-and-kvantour).